# Update Items Records To Match Non-Empty Field

Tags: sql-server

I have a legacy table with a 2 field composite key and a standard character field: `Order_Id, Item_Id, Type`. The problem we've run into is that some of the types are blank, and we want to correct them.

I'm trying to write (if possible) an UPDATE statement that would update any blank records with the type of a non-blank record with the same `Order_Id`. One constraint is that nothing should happen if there are two records with the same `Order_Id` but different types.

```
Order_ID   Item_ID    Type
1          1          'A'
1          2          ''   <-- Update to A, matches Rec 1, 1
2          1          'A'
2          2          'B'
2          3          ''   <-- Can't update because items 1 and 2 differ
```

Can this type of an operation be reasonably done? I've gotten so far as creating a self-joined result set (from which I can update), but I haven't figured out how to deal with different items.

```
SELECT
    a.Order_Id,
    a.Item_Id,
    a.[Type],
    b.[Type]
FROM Order_Item as a
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT DISTINCT b.[Type] FROM Order_Item as b WHERE b.Order_Id = a.Order_ID AND b.[Type] != '') as b
```

Comment: Three answers with three different approaches.  If we get a temp-table and cursor-based suggestion, we'll have hit for the cycle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "update" you do indeed mean `UPDATE`, then you could actually achieve this with a single CTE and a couple of Window Functions:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Order_ID int, Item_ID int, [Type] char(1));

INSERT INTO TestTable (Order_ID, Item_ID, [Type])
VALUES(1,1,'A'),
      (1,2,'' ),
      (2,1,'A'),
      (2,2,'B'),
      (2,3,'' );

GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Order_ID, Item_ID, [Type],
           MIN(NULLIF([Type],'')) OVER (PARTITION BY Order_ID) AS MinType,
           MAX(NULLIF([Type],'')) OVER (PARTITION BY Order_ID) AS MaxType
    FROM TestTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET [Type] = MinType
WHERE [Type] = ''
  AND MinType = MaxType;

SELECT *
FROM TestTable;

GO
DROP TABLE TestTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

This pair of CTE's should give you the Order_ID values that have only one Type assigned to them:

```
;With cte_Distinct_Type
As
(
    Select Distinct 
        oi.Order_ID
        , oi.Item_Type
    From dbo.Order_Item As oi
    Where oi.Item_Type <> ''
), cte_Singleton_Types
As
(
    Select
        cte.Order_ID
        , Count(cte.Order_ID) As Order_Count
    From cte_Distinct_Type As cte
    Group By 
        cte.Order_ID
    Having Count(cte.Order_ID) = 1
)
```

I leave the rest in your capable hands ;)

Answer (score 1):

A very similar approach, but I like windowing functions.

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (
ORDER_ID INT,
Item_ID INT,
Type NCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @mytable
(ORDER_ID, Item_ID, Type)
VALUES
(1,1,'A'), (1,2,''),(1,3,'A'),(2,1,'A'),(2,2,'B'),(2,3,'')


;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT X.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_ID) AS num_types
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_ID, Type
        FROM @mytable
        WHERE Type != ''
    ) AS X
)

UPDATE a
SET a.Type = CTE.Type
FROM @mytable a
INNER JOIN CTE
ON CTE.ORDER_ID = a.ORDER_ID
WHERE CTE.num_types = 1

SELECT * FROM @mytable
```